# how to remove ÿþ characters in csv file at the begining of row?

Tags: php, csv, special-characters, export-to-csv

```
$filename = empty($filename) ? time().'.csv' : $filename.'.csv';
$data = chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
header("Content-type:application/csv");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
echo $data;
exit;
```

when i export into csv, am getting output like this ex:" **ÿþ**". So I need to remove this characters how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$filename = empty($filename) ? time().'.csv' : $filename.'.csv';
$data = chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
$cleanedData = str_replace ( "ÿþID", "" ,  $data);
header("Content-type:application/csv");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
echo $cleanedData;
exit;
```